# Chef download package vs package "apache2"

Tags: chef-infra

I'm very new to Chef and as I learned, to install apache using chef, there are 2 ways:

Method 1) download apache community cookbook at: http://community.opscode.com/cookbooks/apache2 and save the unzip under cookbooks directory

Method 2) in a recipe, default.rb, I can do: package "apache2"

so what is the benefit or differences between these 2 methods? Does method 1 by downloading cookbook will give more control and easy to customize its recipes?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method not only installs apache but also helps in managing the process and customize ,for example:

1. customize your configuration files
2. customize your server modes and modules
3. enable or disable your site
4. restart the apache service when any of the configuration files change
5. and many other things that you should do from scratch if you take the second option

It also lets you customize the installation process only making some changes to the attributes of the recipe like, the site path, the name.

And also this cookbook validate this process for many others platform like:

amazon, arch, centos, debian, fedora, freebsd, redhat, scientific, ubuntu

Comment: so method 2 might not validate the process for other platform? I'm curious in term of best practice like simple solution vs control ability?

Comment: It depends on what you really need. Don't complicate things. If you need just to install a package, with no configuration then #2 is good enough. I, personally, write all cookbooks myself, (sometimes based on community cookbooks) because very often I don't need so much configuration abilities, and thus my cookbooks stay lighter and easier to maintain.

Comment: I tend to prefer using the community cookbooks, as long as they provide me with the options I need. Sometimes they might be more complicated then what you need in the moment, but they scale better by catering for you future needs as well as the present.
About `package`, it does work across all platforms supported by chef, but since package names can differ on different OSs (like Debian's `apache2` vs RHEL's `httpd`), you'd have to manually specify those in your recipe if you need to install on other platforms.

Comment: I use a mix of both. I wrote/maintained many of the community cookbooks for awhile. I tend to prefer resource-based cookbooks (like the new Jenkins one) instead of recipe/attribute-based ones like apache

Comment: Thanks for all feed-backs!